# Table view content missing during scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, scroll, tableview, reuseidentifier

I am using table view cell and adding a pop up view on clicking a button placed in cell .But when I am scrolling the table view view pop is disappearing from my cell. Here is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellF
orRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     NSString *CellIdentifier =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ArticleCell%d  %d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];

    __block ArticleCell_iPad *cell = (ArticleCell_iPad *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[ArticleCell_iPad alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SynopsysViewSharing" owner:self options:nil];

        cell = [[[ArticleCell_iPad alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, kCellWidth_iPad, kCellHeight_iPad)] autorelease];

        __block NSDictionary *currentArticle = [self.articles objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

         [cell.iconImage loadImageWithURL:[[currentArticle objectForKey:@"sourceLogoImg"]objectForKey:@"text"]];


        [cell.sideButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[cellButtonImageArr objectAtIndex:self.selectIndex]]

        [cell.sideButton addTarget:self action:@selector(sideButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        cell.sideButton.tag = indexPath.section;

        TableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

   }
   return cell;
}
```

Button Action:

```
 -(IBAction)sideButtonClicked:(UIButton*)sender
 {

    buttonShare=[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SynopsysViewSharing" owner:self options:nil] lastObject];

    NSIndexPath *myIP = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:sender.tag];
    ArticleCell_iPad *cellSelected = (ArticleCell_iPad*)[_horizontalTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:myIP];

    [cellSelected.contentView addSubview:buttonShare];
    buttonShare.alpha = 0.0f;
    buttonShare.tag=500;
    [buttonShare setFrame:CGRectMake(0,600, cellSelected.frame.size.height,55)];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    [buttonShare setFrame:CGRectMake(0,cellSelected.frame.size.width-55, cellSelected.frame.size.height,55)];
    buttonShare.alpha = 1.0f;
   } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

   }];
}
```

Comment: i have 6 sections.Each section having 1 row.  i can write also    NSString *CellIdentifier =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ArticleCell%d ",indexPath.section];
no need indexpath.row

Comment: i have 6 sections.Each section having 1 row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead adding the **buttonshare** to the contentview through coding, pls try adding your 'buttonshare' in storyboard for the prototype cell itself and make it hidden by checking the hidden property.

And tap on for your button in the UITableviewCell make the hidden property of **buttonshare to "NO" in sideButtonClicked:**

Hope it helps :)

Comment: i am using custom table view cell ArticleCell_iPad.I cant change it further

Comment: I assume your **ArticleCell_iPad** it's a Custom tableviewCell class which you have subclassed from UItableviewCell. You can add a  drag and drop button and create a Iboutllet for the same to perform your actions instead adding to contentview

Comment: I am using horizontal table view .   uitableview-horizontal table view cell-Article table view cell         1.- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
    HorizontalTableCell_iPad *cell = [self.reusableCells objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    return cell;
}  2.with horizontal table view cell for index path i am using article ipad cell

Comment: what do you mean by __HorizontalTableView__ ?

Comment: Within a table view cell i am adding another table view cell is called horizontal table view cell                                                                                      interface HorizontalTableCell_iPad : UITableViewCell <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>  and its content i am setting in article ipad cell   interface ArticleCell_iPad : UITableViewCell

Comment: u can follow                        http://www.raywenderlich.com/4723/how-to-make-an-interface-with-horizontal-tables-like-the-pulse-news-app-part-2

Comment: Ok, now i get it. See that was an old approach for creating that sort of user experience. For now you have **UICollectionView** to create the same experience then you struggling with **UItableView**. Collection will have both horizontal and vertical scrolling exactly the same way you needed it
You can follow the link to create a **UICollectionView** [link](http://adoptioncurve.net/archives/2012/09/a-simple-uicollectionview-tutorial/)

Comment: Oky.. I ll test tonight and let u know.

Comment: i need single line not multiple section.I am not able to add screen shot file here .Can u please share me ur personal mail id

Comment: yes, i have implemented through collection view,but data is not reloading,Can you please help me out ??

Comment: where is it not reloading?

Comment: actually what happens,when i am scrolling horizontally and going to last index & when i am coming back backward scrolling 1st and 2nd content missing,so we cant say it it s not reloading.Please give me some tips asap.

Comment: - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    
    SynopsisCollectionViewCell *playingCardCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"SynopsisCollectionViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    [playingCardCell setPlayingCard:self.reusableCells[indexPath.item] andFrame:playingCardCell.frame andDescription1:@"HI this is for test"];
    return playingCardCell;
}

Answer (score 0):

There are two main things wrong in your implementation:

1. in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, you need to initialise the cell for the given indexPath, even if it is a reused cell (if `cell != nil`).
2. in your `sideButtonClicked`, do **not** call `cellForRowAtIndexPath` in order to find the cell. It will create a completely new cell, instead of returning the one that is on screen. Derive which row it is from the `UIButton` argument of the method instead.

Have a look at [Apple's programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html).